# Intern Leadfoot WaitForAddedById functionality?

Tags: selenium, intern

How can I simulate this feature? It seems like a conscious choice to have a `WaitForDeletedById` but not the reverse.

Upon an ajax load, how can I wait for the existence of a new element on the page, rather than the absence of one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`setFindTimeout`](http://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#setFindTimeout) to set how long the test should wait for an element to exist, then use the normal [`find`](http://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/Command.html#find) methods. The only reason that a special `waitForDeleted` method exists is because it has to use a local polling method to efficiently respond to an element being deleted, whereas waiting for an element until it exists is functionality that is supported natively by the remote Selenium server.